# How to change my toString() output

Tags: java, tostring

Right now the default `toString()` method displays the internal identifier for the object.

How do I make the `toString()` method display object variables instead?

thanks!

Comment: You've got plenty of correct answers but I thought i would just point our that if you are trying to call toString() on an object that's part of the Java API or from some other library then you'll have to create a wrapper around the object (effectively creating your own version of it that only overrides the toString method). Otherwise there is no way to format the output to toString as best I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override [`toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) on the class you want the information about.

For example:

```
class Foo {
    private String myProperty = "bar";

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return myProperty;
    }
}
```

In the above example, you would see the following:

```
new Foo().toString(); // outputs "bar"
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to override the toString method on your class.  In it you return a String that you will construct based on the class properties.

So if you class was

```
class Person {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
}
```

you would add

```
public String toString() {
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
}
```

thats just a basic example.  In real code I would use String.format() method, or possibly the apache StringBuilder tool, which will automatically generate a String for any object.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
  String yourString = "";

  //Do things to get what you want

  return yourString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inherit the class and override its toString() method to display whatever you want.